# WooCommerce - Updating an order when status is not 'pending'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some custom fields ([ACF plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)) for my WooCommerce orders.

Problem is, that unless the 'Order Status' is set to `wc-pending` (i.e. Payment Pending), changes to the custom field will not save.

After spending many hours trying to debug the issue (with PHP XDebug), I've learned the following:

- Order status is actually stored as the posts `post_status`
- There seems to be a conflict on the WooCommerce 'edit order' page: `post_status` is both a WooCommerce input field, and a Wordpress input field
- When an order is editable (i.e. it's `post_status == 'wc-pending'`) data that is posted back from the 'edit order' page has `$_POST['post_status'] = 'pending'` (not `wc-pending`) as expected
- When an order is not editable `$_POST['post_status'] = 'wc-processing'` (for example)

Please help! I understand that it is probably a good idea not to edit an order once the customer has paid for it. The custom fields need to be filled in once the order is taken.

Comment: OK - I've given up looking for an elegant solution to this. I simply modified the abstract-wc-order.php file to call wp_update_post regardless of a change of status. This triggers all of the relevant hooks. Not ideal, but I can't find another way.